# Inherited parse method conflict in scala

Tags: scala, playframework, reactivemongo, body-parser, play-reactivemongo

I'm working through some compilation errors (in *Scala / Play Framework*) and one I can't resolve is a conflict error. This is the error:

> class Games inherits conflicting members:
>
> [error] method parse in trait BaseControllerHelpers of type => play.api.mvc.PlayBodyParsers and
>
> [error] lazy value parse in trait BodyParsers of type
> play.api.mvc.PlayBodyParsers [error] (Note: this can be resolved by
> declaring an override in class Games.)

And this is the *function (or class) signature* for the class:

```
   class Games @Inject() (cc: ControllerComponents, actorSystem: ActorSystem)(val reactiveMongoApi: ReactiveMongoApi)(implicit mat: Materializer) extends AbstractController(cc) with MongoController with ReactiveMongoComponents {
```

In the error message you'll notice that it says that:

> this can be resolved by declaring an override in class Games

But after having tried a few things - I am not sure how. If anyone has any suggestions on this or any other technique that could resolve this error please post. Thanks

Comment: There is conflict between the new (Play 2.6) `AbstractController` and `MongoController`, the former being based on the deprecated `Controller` trait. Play 2.6 backward compat prevent such mix of `AbstractController` / `Controller`. Until that's fix the only workaround is to remove.

Comment: @cchantep thanks. If this is the issue why does neither the *ReactiveMongo* or *Play Framework* documentation acknowledge this? There's information on how to integrate them here -
 http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.12/documentation/tutorial/play.html so why wouldn't they have tested them? Seems totally ridiculous. So is the answer not to use Play 2.6?

Comment: @cchantep and also - is there really no *override* that can resolve this?

Comment: I can hardly see a way with the inheritance changes in Play MVC

Comment: Having the same issue, what is the solution here? This kind of thing has happened every time I've tried getting started with Play

Comment: @jesusg_forceHarris   You can work around the issue by adding this override to your controller: `override lazy val parse: PlayBodyParsers = cc.parsers`

Comment: You can try ReactiveMongo 0.12.5-SNAPSHOT

Comment: @samsquanch Thanks it got rid of the error but I have noticed that on some pages I am getting a "Unauthorized. You must be authenticated to access this page." - which I never saw with Play 2.5. I'll look into it tomorrow

Comment: @samsquanch - feel free to put your solution in an answer and I will mark it correct. Thanks again

Comment: I had this issue on play 2.6.7 and reactivemongo 0.12.7 and scala 2.12.4. @cchantep's suggestion works perfectly. removed `play.modules.reactivemongo.MongoController` from the class inherits.